# Sum of Log AR(1) processes

Tags: st.statistics

I have two AR(1) processes that look like this:
$x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+\eta_t$
and
$y_t=\rho y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$
where $0<\rho<1$ and $\eta_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta})$ and $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})$.

My question is can $exp(x_t)+exp(y_t)$ be represented (or approximated) by $exp(z_t)$ where $z_t$ follows some AR(1) process?

I know that if $x_t$ and $y_t$ are independent normals then $exp(x_t)+exp(y_t)$ can be approximated by some $exp(z_t)$ where $z_t$ follows a normal distribution, but things get complicated when $x_t$ and $y_t$ are auto-regressive processes, which is my problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Dear all, I just want to do a quick follow up on this question. It would be extremely helpful even if the answer is "no." Thanks again for your time!